# Can Spring Mobile Treat iOS and Android Differently?

Tags: ios, spring, spring-mvc, mobile-website, spring-mobile

Spring Mobile allows a Spring MVC application to detect whether a web client is a desktop/laptop, tablet, or mobile device.

Is it possible to determine if a device is Android/iOS using Spring Mobile? Are there extension points for this, or would it be 'homebrew' functionality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spring Mobile does not include built in support to differentiate between Android and iOS. However, it includes two interfaces, `Device` and `DeviceResolver`. You can implement custom versions of these that detect Android and iOS devices and offer additional methods, such as `isAndroid()` or `isIOS()` for example. Then you can configure `DeviceResolverHandlerInterceptor` to use your `DeviceResolver` implementation. When you use the detected device in a `Controller` you can simply cast it to your implementation. Review the provided `LiteDevice` and `LiteDeviceResolver` implementations for inspiration.

Answer (score 1):

I know that this ticket is quite old, but I just wanted to inform you that it is possible with newer versions of spring-mobile-device.

In the latest 1.1.5.RELEASE you can easily access the Device's DevicePlatform. See https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-mobile/blob/1.1.5.RELEASE/spring-mobile-device/src/main/java/org/springframework/mobile/device/DevicePlatform.java

So if you use 1.1.5.RELEASE, you can easily do something like this:

```
if (currentDevice.isNormal()) {
  // do stuff for desktop devices
} elseif (currentDevice.getDevicePlattform() == DevicePlatform.IOS) {
  // do iOS specific stuff
} else {
  // treat as mobile device
}
```